# Run frequent background task on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

Windows Phone platform offers BackgroundTasks infrastructure. I can register my task like that:

```
builder.TaskEntryPoint = TaskName;
var trigger = new TimeTrigger(15, false);

builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
builder.Register();
```

The problem is, that TimeTrigger min interval is ~15 minutes, which is pretty large for my application. I need to have task which runs every 1-2 minutes in the background. Is it possible on Windows Phone?

Comment: Windows phone OS restricts, due to battery draining. Also in windows phone 8.1, User can remove app from battery saver, Hence no task will run in background.

So you have to handle that also  




Channel 9 reference :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have BackgroundTasks that run on a minute interval basis.
As you said already the minimum interval is 15 minute.

This is an OS limitation to prevent developers to build battery draining applications.

You always have some workarounds, like having a PushNotificationTrigger, and manage to send a push notification to your device every minute. (I guess some people manage to do so with the `ScheduledToastNotification`), but i wouldn't recomend it.

Comment: Andre is correct. What you have described appears to be a design issue in your app. You should be asking yourself why are you trying to pull (or poll) data every 1-2 minutes? Are you looking for something to change? This is a poor design practice for a mobile device and should have information pushed to it only when data changes. Secondly, network data consumption should not be consumed unless absolutely necessary. I can only guess at what you are doing, but you should reconsider whether there is a need that cannot be designed in a passive mode versus an active mode.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK with the official API - it's not possible to run *TimeTrigger* so often. Note that on WIndows Phone, the interval is even larger ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx)):

> Windows has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals. Note that on Windows Phone, the interval is 30 minutes.

I doubt it will be possible, due to battery consuption/restrictions. Maybe you can leave your app in the foreground and disable lockscreen (by using *DisplayRequest*).

Also you may try to run a timer along with obtaining deferal in your BackgroundTask. I've not tried that, for sure there will be many problems (CPU limit, memory and other restrictions), I'm not sure if that is not against certification requirements and of course it doesn't guarantee that your BackgroundTask wouldn't be terminated by OS.